# Java - Lists and methods

Tags: java, oop

I have an abstract class named Spell. Spell class suppose to have few subclasses, like DamageSpell, ChangeStatSpell etc.

The problem is technical  - in DamageSpell class - right after the declaration of damage method - it says that it can't find getSpell (java can't find symbol : method getSpell(). How can I fix this? I'd appreciate a code example that describes how to fix it. Thanks.

```
abstract public  class Spell {
    private String name;
    private int spellLevel;
    private int manaCost;

    Spell(String name, int spellLevel , int manaCost){
        this.name = name;
        this.spellLevel = spellLevel;
        this.manaCost = manaCost;
    }


    String getSpellName(){ return name; }
    int getSpellLevel() {return spellLevel; }
    int getManaCost(){ return manaCost; }
}
```

```
public class DamageSpell extends Spell {

private int n;
private int dice;
private int base;
private int stepLevel;
private int maxCasterLevel;


DamageSpell(String name, int spellLevel, int manaCost, int n, int dice, int base, int stepLevel, int maxCasterLevel){
    super(name, spellLevel, manaCost);
    this.n = n;
    this.dice = dice;
    this.base = base;
    this.stepLevel = stepLevel;
    this.maxCasterLevel = maxCasterLevel;
}


static List<DamageSpell> damageSpellsList = new ArrayList<DamageSpell>();

static
{
    damageSpellsList.add(new DamageSpell("Magic Missiles", 1, 2,   1, 4, 1, 2, 9));
    //  damageSpellsList.add(new DamageSpell("Scorching Ray ", 2, 4));
    damageSpellsList.add(new DamageSpell("Fireball", 3, 6,   1, 6, 1, 1, 10));
    //damageSpellsList.add(new DamageSpell("Ice Storm", 4, 8));
}





public static void damage(String spellName, Character attacker, Character target){


    DamageSpell spell = damageSpellsList.getSpell(spellName);

    int damage = 0;

    int casterLevel = Math.min(attacker.getLevel(), spell.maxCasterLevel);
    int totalRolls = (casterLevel-spell.base)%spell.stepLevel;

    for (int i = 1; i <= totalRolls ; i++) {
        damage += DiceRoller.roll(spell.n, spell.dice);

    }

    target.setCurrentHp(target.getCurrentHp() - damage);
    System.out.println(" You dealt " + damage + " to the enemy");

}

public DamageSpell getSpell(String spellName) {
    try {
        for (Iterator<DamageSpell> iter = damageSpellsList.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
            DamageSpell spell = iter.next();
            if (spellName.equals(spell.getSpellName())) {
                return spell;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(spellName + " haven't been found in spells-list");
        return null;
    }
    return null;

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your getSpell(" ") problem is quite simple. You are doing `damageSpellsList.getSpell(spellName);`, `damageSpellsList` is a `List<T>`, and Lists don't have a `getSpell()` method (or any Collection in general).

What you will have to do is access the `Object` that the List is storing at a certain index of the `List<T>` by using `List#get(i)` or iterating over the `List` entirely using a for loop or an `Iterator`.

Comment: Ohh, I missed something. In the former version of my files another class used MageSpellsList.getSpell() that operated on mageSpellsList, so I had no problem. I copied that, and changed a few letters, but I haven't noticed that  a class called getSpell and here it was a list. Silly me :)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `getSpell(...)` on your damageSpellsList variable which is an ArrayList and which of course will not have that method. You need to call it on an element in the List and not on the List itself. But having said that, I see that your method body uses only static elements, and so perhaps the `getSpell(...)` method should be static as well and called on the DamageSpell class. I'm not sure though that I like this design, and perhaps the List should be non-static and held in its own class.

Also for similar questions, always post the complete error message that you're seeing.

---

Suggestions:

- Consider creating a SpellBook class
- Within this class, have a non-static `List<Spell>`
- If you will only get Spell by name String, then the collection should not be a List/ArrayList but rather should be a `HashMap<String, Spell>`, making it much easier to retrieve the spell by name.
- Give this class a `public Spell getSpell(String name)` method
- Perhaps the Spell class needs a `cast(owner, target)` method for when the Spell holder decides to use or "cast" his spell.

Comment: The design is bad, if you have an idea how to improve it, then don't hesitate :)

Comment: Spellbook can be a list that Mage has. When I had just MageSpellsList of type Spell I had a problem, and people here suggested to use static. How should I do it ?

Comment: Using  HashMap<String, Spell>  would require casting to perform actions? (because Spell has a partial data). You mean that spellbook will be a hashmap, right ?

Comment: public Spell getSpell(String name). - Why it's better to return Spell rather than DamageSpell ?

Comment: Another thing regarding - Within this class, have a non-static List<Spell> - This list will have objects of type Spell, which means that it won't include DamageSpell's fields with its relevant data.